# アプリケーションサーバとwebサーバの違い。

Tags: python, nginx, heroku, google-app-engine, flask

どうしてローカルではアプリケーションサーバ（Flask）のみで動作するのにGAEやherokuにアップロードするとGunicornやApache、nginxが必要になるのですか？
色々種類あるwebサーバは何が違うのですか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gunicorn → アプリケーションサーバー
ApahceやNGinx → Webサーバー
Flask → PythonのWebアプリケーション フレームワーク
になるかと思います。

Flask には、サーバー機能が組み込まれてはいますが、開発やテストをすることを主眼に用意されており、性能、安定性、セキュリティなどは考慮されておらず、簡素な物です。

本番運用する場合は Gunicorn などの アプリケーションサーバー（WSGI サーバー）を利用するのが推奨されています。

Gunicorn は Pythonで実装された WSGI サーバーで、Webサーバーとしての機能もあるので Gunicorn単体でも動きますが、Nginx と組み合わせるのが強く推奨されていて、外部からの攻撃に強くなるのが理由として挙げられてます。
http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/deploy.html

Apacheと、Nginxは どちらも人気で実績の多いHTTPサーバーです。違いはとても書ききれませんが、超々ざっくり特徴を書くと

- Apacheは歴史が古く 長い期間をかけて 拡張されてきた ど定番 Webサーバー。
- Nginxは比較的新しくて設定がシンプルなので 今は これが一押し Webサーバー。

こんな感じかと。

Comment: GunicornとさらにNginxを使うとは知りませんでした。詳しくありがとうございます。

Answer (score 6):

> Apache、nginxが必要になるのですか？

ApacheやNginxなどのWebサーバをAPサーバのフロントに配置する主な目的は、以下のようなことだと思います。

- 負荷分散
- セキュリティの強化
- 静的ファイルの処理の高速化
- Webサーバにしかない機能の利用

Webサーバが無くても要件を満たせるのであれば、APサーバだけでも問題無いです。

> 色々種類あるwebサーバは何が違うのですか？

機能やアーキテクチャなどいろいろ違います。「Apache vs Nginx」とか「Apache Nginx 比較」とかでググればたくさん情報が出てきます。