# JavaかPythonでのHTTPサーバー構築はどちらの方が良いのか

Tags: python, java, http, サーバー管理

現在、とあるプロジェクトでWebサイトを作っています。
そこで現在、HTTPサーバーを構築する必要が出てき、JavaかPython、どちらの言語を使ってサーバー構築をするべきなのか迷っています。
PythonでもJavaでも両方ともHTTPサーバー構築は可能と聞きましたが、どちらのほうがセキュリティー面、速さなどで優勢でしょうか。　そのWebサイトはユーザーのパスワードやIDを管理する予定なので、セキュリティー面をなるべく重視したいです。

また、もしできればそれぞれの言語でのサーバーを構築するにあたっての利点をお聞きしたいです。

文章の書き方がところどころ荒く申し訳ございません。
どなたかわかる方、お力添えいただけると嬉しいです。

Comment: 真に httpd を実装するんですか？ backend じゃなくて？ 今時 httpd の自前実装などセキュリティ面ではありえないです。

Comment: [XY 問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701) のようにも見えますが、「Java や Python で HTTP サーバを構築する」のが目的ですか？それとも「HTTP サーバを構築するのが主目的で、Java や Python は候補に過ぎない」のどちらでしょうか？

Comment: 返信が遅くなり申し訳ございません。
自分は、JavaかPythonでHTTPサーバーを構築するのが目的です。

Comment: 「HTTPサーバを自作する」と「HTTPサーバを構築する」は別の話です。質問から見るに市場の無料有料のソフトウェアを利用せず、自前でソフトウェアを開発し「HTTPサーバを自作する」ように見えてしまいますがそれで間違いないですか？それとも様々なソフトウェアを利用してインストールをして「HTTPサーバを構築する」が目的ですか？

Comment: 申し訳ございません。私の伝え方が悪かったですね。
自分はできれば後者のApacheやTomCatを使う、「構築」スタイルで行きたいと思っています。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

コメントのやりとりをするかぎり
「HTTPサーバ」を開発する言語ではなくて、「Webアプリケーション（バックエンド・サーバサイド）」の開発するための言語は何がいいかという質問と推察されます。

バックエンドの技術選択は「環境」や「プロダクト」や「プロジェクト」様々な要素に影響して決定が難しい質問です。例えば誰が保守するのか？言語に対してどのぐらい習得度なのか？どういった機能を作る必要があるのか？
それらのコストやリスクの検討はもちろん、さらには将来性や今後の言語の発展性なども踏まえるとかなり広範囲で考える必要が出てきます。

セキュリティーを重視したいとありますが、どの言語やフレームワークでも脆弱性は都度報告されていますし、完全なものはないです。[こちら](https://jvndb.jvn.jp/index.html)でいろいろ検索してみてください。
また言語やフレームワークがきちんとしていてもご自身のアプリケーションの設計や実装にセキュリティホールがあると無駄になってしまいます。つまりはご自身の設計力やエンジニア力に影響してきます。

組織であるならば間違いなく事業の将来性や会社の未来にかかわってくるので、慎重に検討してみてください。CTOや事業責任者との会話が必要です。
もし個人で勉強のためということであれば、ご自身がやりたい言語をやってみるとよいでしょう。

また「HTTPサーバ」と「Webアプリケーション（バックエンド・サーバサイド）」の違いには注意してください。
HTTPサーバと書いてしまうと、クライアントとHTTPプロトコルを通信するサーバ自体をさしてしまいます。（Apache等）
HTTPプロトコルでやり取りした結果を受取処理し返すjavaやpythonの部分は「Webアプリケーション」「バックエンド」「サーバサイド」と呼ばれます。

Comment: 長文、ご丁寧にありがとうございます。
この回答を見て、私の未熟さを痛感しました。
今回の私が作っているものは練習を目当てとした個人の物で、keitaro_soさんの仰るとおり、好きな言語での開発に望んでみようと思います。
また、回答者様のおかげで曖昧になっていた「Apache」などのソフトウェアと「HTTPサーバー」や、「Java」などのバックエンドサーバーサイドの違いがはっきりしました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

Java や Python に限らず、大抵のプログラミング言語では web サーバの機能を再現できますが、これらはあくまで簡易的なものであり「リクエストを受け取って応答を返す」位しかできません。

主な用途は動作検証等なので、本番環境として外部に公開する場合や、セキュリティ等を考慮する必要があるなら Apache 等の Web サーバの使用を検討すべきです。

関連質問:
[アプリケーションサーバとwebサーバの違い](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/51889)

Comment: java/python では簡易な httpd しか実装できないってこともないし、質問者氏が今から（フルスペックな） httpd を実装しようとしてるんだから、この回答ではちょっと外れているかも。性能が出るとかその辺はおいといて。